# How to disable the warning for pragma message in Clang?

Tags: clang, warnings, message, pragma

`#pragma message` is implemented in Clang as warning.
Is there any way to disable the warning only for this pragma, so it will be have like MS Visual Studio,  or some other way to give informational messages from code ?
(I need an answer as an end user with a given Clang, I cannot re-compile the Clang itself on this project)

Answer (score 6):

I realize this post is a year old and the OP probably already found his answer but since I was looking for the answer myself I thought I may as well include the info here.

From the Clang user's manual:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas

> The pragma may control any warning that can be used from the command line. Warnings may be set to ignored, warning, error, or fatal.

Attempting to set the class to something other than the above:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic note "-W#pragma-messages"
#pragma message "HELLO!"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}
```

Results in a warning showing the same options:

```
/tmp/test.cc:3:26: warning: pragma diagnostic expected 'error', 'warning', 'ignored', 'fatal', 'push', or 'pop' [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma clang diagnostic note "-W#pragma-messages"
                          ^
/tmp/test.cc:4:9: warning: HELLO! [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message "HELLO!"
         ^
2 warnings generated.
```

So it appears that as of Clang 5.0 there is no way to treat the message as informational instead of as a warning.

Comment: seems to be the case in clang 12, `#pragma message ...` appears twice in the messages, once as warning and then as message.

Comment: I can add `#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic warning "-W#pragma-messages" ... etc` but in that case the message will be removed completely.